# convert a date string into long in Android

Tags: android, datetime

I have a date string: `02/28/2013 06:20:00 PM`

I have a date formater: `SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");`

```
java.util.Date tempDate;
```

when I parse the string with the formater and extract the date

```
tempDate = dateFmt.parse(xpp.getText());
```

I get a date that is off by 12 hours:  `Thu, Feb 28, 2013 6:20 AM`

What am i overlooking?

Comment: Perhaps it's transforming it to a different timezone?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"); should be new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy bla bla ?

Comment: I am executing: dateFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); before parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadocs for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) say that `HH` is for the hour in 24-hour format (0-23).  For AM/PM format (1-12) you should use `hh`.